# jQuery Validate function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

This problem, i am sure is very trivial but i am not able to get past it.

My form is not getting validated using jquery validate.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#loginForm").validate({
                rules: {
                    email: "required",
                    passwd: "required",
                    email:{
                        minlength: 10
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    email: "Please enter your email",
                    passwd: "Please enter your passwd",
                    email:{
                        minlength: "Minlength has to be 10"
                    }
                },

                submitHandler: function(form) {
                    $("#pp").text("right");
                    form.submit();
                }
            }); 
        })
```

No console errors. I have following

name, passwd are name, id of the fields i am trying to validate and loginForm is id of form. The problem is i don't see the error messages when i pass invalid input. Going through debug mode, i don't see the stack reaching inside validate function ever although an alert inside ready function before validate is called.

Comment: please post your code (html + js)

Comment: We need to see the HTML for this form.

Comment: In two objects (rules and messages) you are overwriting the value of the "email" key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not show your HTML markup, so this answer assumes you correctly named your `input` elements.

In your code, you're specifying `email` twice...

```
rules: {
    email: "required",
    passwd: "required",
    email:{  // <- duplicate
        minlength: 10
    }
},
```

If you need to specify multiple rules for one field, then specify the field *once* and list the rules inside...

```
rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 10
    },
    passwd: "required"
},
```

Your `messages` option has the same problem.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/4937t/**